# Put row value in quotes, based on values in other row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this (Dots represent spaces):

```
     Col1   | Col2     | Col3
  ------------------------------------
0 |  ..Val1 | ....Val2 | ...Val3
1 |  6      | 8        | 7
```

First row contains values with spaces. The spaces must be retained.

Second row contains numeric values that tell how long the values in the first line are.

I want the values in the first row to be enclosed in quotes based on the values in the second row. (value + space).

The final result should look like this:

```
     Col1     | Col2       | Col3
  ----------------------------------------
0 |  "..Val1" | "....Val2" | "...Val3"
1 |  6        | 8          | 7
```

Comment: "The final result should look like this" should be followed with your attempt, which should then be followed with what you are having problems with. Have you attempted to solve this by yourself ? If so, with what problem do you need help ?

Comment: Can you share what are you trying ?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want? imagining that the second of column 1 has a value 7 what is the expected result?

Comment: Is first row generate the second row, or vise versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this if the first row is generated by second row :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['', 6], 'Col2': ['', 8], 'Col3': ['', 7]})
#print original df
print(df)
#Get Second row
df_second_row = df.iloc[1]
for i in range(0,len(df_second_row)):
    # Create New str
    new_str = "Val"+str(i+1)
    # Calculate number of dot 
    dot_value = df_second_row[i] - len(new_str)
    print("Add for "+new_str+": "+str(dot_value)+" dots")
    # Create new value for first row based on second row
    df.iloc[0][i] = '"' +'{:.>{width}}'.format(new_str, width=df_second_row[i])+ '"' 

#Final output
print(df)
```

**Result :**

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
0  
1    6    8    7
Add for val1: 2 dots
Add for val2: 4 dots
Add for val3: 3 dots
      Col1      Col2     Col3 
0  "..Val1"  "....Val2"  "...Val3" 
1         6           8          7
```